# itemno.1.Prove that $f(x,y)=\left(x^2 y,x-y\right)$ is continuous at $(2,-1)$ item no 2.Prove that $f(x) =\frac{x-2}{x-1}$ is continuous at $x=2$

Tags: real-analysis

no.1) Prove that $f(x,y)=\left(x^2y,x-y\right)$ is continuous at $(2,-1)$.and
no.2) Prove that the function $f(x) = \frac{x-2}{x-1}$ is continuous at $x = 2$.

Comment: 1. the title should be a summarize of the content, not the content itselfe.....
2. we are not here to do your homework. Try at least to write what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck....

Comment: i'm sorry,,but i really don't know how to start..i just took the chance that somebody would help me understand this lesson. =(

Comment: What Definition of Continuous did you have?

Comment: continous if a function is defined at a particular value.am i correct?tnx sir borge.

Comment: Every function is defined at a particular function in the Domain. There are a lot of equivalent definitions of continuous. The most common one is the "$\epsilon-\delta$ definition.  Other definitions use sequences or open sets. Does one of them sound familiar?

Comment: of cause I meant value in the domain ;)

Comment: does this problem an open set?how will i start to prove this function??will i just substitute the point (2,-1) to the given ordered pair?in number 1?the same procedure in number two?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's start with the second one.
I will not show you the complete proof but I will give you a start.

$f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x-1}$ is continuous at $x=2$. Here I will show you how you can start with sequences. Let $\left(x_n\right)$ be a arbitrary sequence with $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x_n=a$
So we use: f is continuous at $a$ $\Leftrightarrow f(a)=f\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x_n\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f\left(x_n\right)$  observe that you need this statement for all sequences and we can't use a specific sequence.  Now we start with $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f\left(x_n\right)$ and use the known limit rules to show that this is equal to $f(a)$

the 2nd start I will write tomorrow ;)